# How to switch modes when operating on multiple selected lines

Tags: vim

I have created a line selection in Vim by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and followed by <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>.

I can do something against all lines separately like `:normal ^i//`, which moves the cursor to the beginning of each line and enter insert mode, then insert two `/`.

Is it possible to switch back to normal mode after this?

The example in the question is just to demonstrate the problem and I only want to discuss the Vim usage skills.

I tried `:normal ^i//<Esc>A//` in the hope of adding two `/` to the end of each line, but it didn't work.

Is this possible?

Comment: You look to be doing some commenting. There are [commenting plugins](https://vimawesome.com/?q=comment) which makes this particular task easier. I personally, use [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary)

Comment: PS `^i` is more or less the same as `I`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `:normal` command does not interpret special characters. In your last try, all the chars after `i` would be interpreted as normal text then inserted at the beginning of each selected line: `//<Esc>A//`.

The <kbd>Esc</kbd> character is a special char (actually the ASCII code 27), so you have to ask Vim to insert this char in a different way (because hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> would escape the command line).

In order to do this (either in Command mode or Insert mode), press <kbd>Ctrl + V</kbd> then the wanted key, e.g. <kbd>Esc</kbd>. This will insert the *real* `<esc>` character in you flow, then perform the desired behaviour.

To summarize:

- Press <kbd>Shift + V</kbd> followed by <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>...
- Type `:normal ^i//`<kbd>Ctrl + V</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>`A//`
- Hit <kbd>Return</kbd> to validate the command